# org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.testng.TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, web-services, jersey-2.0

I have project in eclipse it's an `WebService` Project REST API's and i have also added another project in `Configure Build path -> Add Project` and i have added one another Project in my API method i am calling `TestNGCreator` class look below.

Basically this project uses jersey framework in java creating REST API and when i am calling any perticular method i.e. execute it will call another class which resides in another project i have added project in Build path of this project my other methods are working fine but when i am calling method from different project i having this error.

Do i need to declare some where that i am using this class and this method in POM.xml or some where else

I need to run the automation by calling this `TestNGCreator.main(null);`
my another project is automation project in java `TestNGCreator` class resides in automation project.By calling this method i need to call above class and when i am doing it i am getting error.

Error :

```
    May 17, 2019 4:20:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/webservices] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    at testDrivers.TestNGCreator.runTestNGTest(TestNGCreator.java:44)
    at testDrivers.TestNGCreator.main(TestNGCreator.java:165)
    at com.xyz.webservices.Resource.executeScript(Resource.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

File  : Resource.java

```
      @POST
      @Path("/execute")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Response executeScript(String data) throws JSONException
        {   
            ArrayList<Object> testCases = new ArrayList<Object>();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            String configFile = (String) json.get("ConfigFiles");
            String sheetName = (String) json.get("Sheetname");
            jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("testCases");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)
            {
                testCases.add(jsonArray.get(i));
            }

            try {
                TestNGCreator.main(null); //here  i am calling that class main method
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Response response = null;
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
            System.out.println(testCases);
            return response;
        }
```

File : TestNGCreator.java

```
package testDrivers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import projlib.Globals;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;




public class TestNGCreator 
{

    public void runTestNGTest() throws IOException 
    {

            System.out.println("Print this line in console");
            //Create an instance on TestNG
            TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

            //Create an instance of XML Suite and assign a name for it.
            XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();
            mySuite.setName(Globals.SUITE_NAME);

            //Create a list of XmlTests and add the Xmltest you created earlier to it.
            List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();

            XSSFSheet excelWSheet = null;
            XSSFWorkbook excelWBook = null;
            XSSFCell cell = null;
            XSSFRow row = null;

            Double dblCellVal;
            String strCellVal = null;
            Boolean blnCellVal;

            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(Globals.CONFIG_FILE_DIR+"/CropRecordConfig.xlsx");
            excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet("CropAdd");


            Iterator <Row> rowIterator = excelWSheet.iterator(); 
            //Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            String testName = null;
            int colCount;

            if (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                colCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            }
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                int curCell = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
                    curCell++;
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        dblCellVal = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        strCellVal = dblCellVal.toString();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        strCellVal = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        blnCellVal = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        strCellVal = blnCellVal.toString();
                        break;
                    }

                    //If it is first cell then store the Test Name
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex()== 0)
                    {
                        testName = strCellVal;
                    }

                    if (curCell == 5) {
                        if (strCellVal.equals("1.0")) {
                            //Adding to suite
                            //Create an instance of XmlTest and assign a name for it.
                            XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);
                            myTest.setName(testName);

                            //Add any parameters that you want to set to the Test.
                            Map<String, String> testngParams = new HashMap<String,String> ();
                            testngParams.put("testId", testName);
                            myTest.setParameters(testngParams);

                            //Create a list which can contain the classes that you want to run.
                            List<XmlClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass> ();
                            myClasses.add(new XmlClass("TestDriver"));

                            //Assign that to the XmlTest Object created earlier.
                            myTest.setXmlClasses(myClasses);

                            //Adding the test to test list created earlier
                            myTests.add(myTest);
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            excelWBook.close();

            //add the list of tests to your Suite.
            mySuite.setTests(myTests);

            //Add the suite to the list of suites.
            List<XmlSuite> mySuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
            mySuites.add(mySuite);

            //Set the list of Suites to the testNG object you created earlier.
            myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);

            File file = new File(Globals.TESTNG_FILE_NAME);
            System.out.println("File is: " + file);

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(mySuite.toXml());
            writer.close();

            //invoke run() - this will run your class.
            //myTestNG.run();




    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        TestNGCreator testDriver = new TestNGCreator();
        testDriver.runTestNGTest();
    }
}
```

File : POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webservices</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>webservices</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
             <version>20080701</version>
       </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated thank you ^.^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see the test-ng dependency in your pom file.
Please add the below and try.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response but i have tried this already and why do i need testng depenedency in maven my other project uses is TestNG not this one and for that i already added the libraries

Comment: and if i execute that file directly by right clicking and run as java application it executes but when i call here i am having this exceptions

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your scenario. But you will need to add the testng dependency whichver project you are using the classes from the testng jar. In the code snippet provided by you, you have used TestNG class in TestNGCreator.java so whichever project has this Java file, you should add the required dependency.

Comment: It sounds to me like perhaps because you've added the TestNG project to the web services project's classpath and then you're attempting to run the TestNG code during the execution of the servlet itself inside of Jersey, the TestNG dependency is not available inside of the servlet container (Catalina) itself. Without knowing more about what your project setup looks like it's hard to give you a solution, but the above comments are correct, you need to add the TestNG dependency with test scope to the test project.

Comment: @adammtlx you mean to say that i should add Web project into automation project with the help of jar or by adding project into build path of automation project

Comment: You'll need to ensure that the TestNG artifact you are referencing in your pom.xml is also available in your Tomcat instance. Typically you'd make these available in the war file you're deploying to Tomcat, but because you are using test scope these artifacts are not available to Tomcat (test scope suppresses target artifact from final package). Try changing the TestNG dependency scope from test to compile (default) or runtime. To check, build your war, then extract the contents of your war file and make sure you can find the TestNG jar file somewhere inside of it. Then deploy war to Tomcat.